# Selecting records from MYSQL table that were created in the last 24 hours via TIMESTAMP type

Tags: mysql, select

I need to output a list of the records created in the last 24 hours (keyword hours, not last day) from a mysql table via php.  I have a column in the table labled 'timestamp' that is set to default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I'm trying something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM list WHERE timestamp > I-have-no-clue-what-to-put-here";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $row['itemname'] . " " . $row['itemurl'];
}
?>
```

Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

See [docs for DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Comment: Rolanda MySQLDBA, you are a gentleman and a scholar.  That did the trick.